# Resultado undefined quando chama função em calculadora

Tags: javascript, funções, argumento

Este *script* para calculo porém ele retorna `undefined`, onde estou errando?

```
var num1 = parseInt(prompt("Digite um número: "))
var operacao = prompt("Digite a operação: ")
var num2 = parseInt(prompt("Digite outro número: "))

function calculo(num1, num2, operacao){
  if (operacao == 'soma'){
    resultado = num1 + num2
    return resultado
  } else if (operacao == 'subtracao'){
    resultado = num1 - num2
    return resultado
  }
}

document.write(calculo())
```

Comment: Você está invocando a função sem passar nenhum argumento.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Po que você não está passando os argumentos para a função.

Eu aproveitei e melhorei a legibilidade do código, colocando junto o que é junto, colocando `;` porque assim funciona mas tem caso que dá problema e aí você ficará procurando sem entender o erro (acostume-se fazer certo, não custa digitar um caractere a mais para dar mais robustez ao código) e retirei a criação da variável que não fazia sentido ali, principalmente porque na forma postada ela é criada em escopo global e isto não deveria acontecer.

O código ainda corre riscos se algo for digitado errado, mas isso é só melhoria.

```js
function calculo(num1, num2, operacao){
    if (operacao == 'soma') return num1 + num2;
    else if (operacao == 'subtracao') return num1 - num2;
}

var num1 = parseInt(prompt("Digite um número: "));
var operacao = prompt("Digite a operação: ");
var num2 = parseInt(prompt("Digite outro número: "));
document.write(calculo(num1, num2, operacao));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/429521/101).

O código funcionaria se a função não tivesse parâmetros, já que as variáveis de escopo global serial usadas diretamente pela função, mas não é ideal fazer isto, estou dizendo para completeza de informação. Como tem parâmetros e nada é enviado para eles então os valores ficam indefinidos.

Answer (score 2):

Você definiu 3 argumentos na função, porém ao chamá-la não os forneceu, por isso ela não funciona, só precisa fornecer os dados para dar certo:

```js
var num1 = parseInt(prompt("Digite um número: "))
var operacao = prompt("Digite a operação: ")
var num2 = parseInt(prompt("Digite outro número: "))

function calculo(num1, num2, operacao){
  if (operacao == 'soma'){
    resultado = num1 + num2
    return resultado
  } else if (operacao == 'subtracao'){
    resultado = num1 - num2
    return resultado
  }
}

document.write(calculo(num1, num2, operacao))
```